# Is Oracle Instant Client an actual database?

Tags: oracle, client, instant

I want to create a small dev database just to use for developing my application. I've downloaded the Oracle Instant client and followed the directions to "install" (ie, copy/paste and set up some environment variables), but I can't find any information on how to connect, login, create database, etc, or even exactly what Instant Client is, specifically. So, a few specific questions:

1. Is Instant client just a set of drivers and components that allow you to connect to an existing database, or can you use Instant Client to create and administer a completely new database?

If it CAN be used to create a new database:

1. How do you "start" (or similar concept) the database so that it is ready for connections.
2. Because there is no installation, and no default configuration, I haven't set up a default schema, port, etc. So, what is the default connection information to connect to the database for the first time? 
   For example, I use SQL Developer to connect to and administer my remote database, so how could I connect to Instant Client from SQL Developer?

Comment: `instantclient`, as the name suggests, is, well, just a client. No, it's not the RDBMS itself. If you need, as you put it, a `small dev database` take a look at Oracle XE edition. [x64](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html). [x86](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html)

Comment: I'm mainly from a SQL Server background, so I find the expansive oracle landscape difficult to navigate with various options for server, odac, ODBC drivers, instant client, SQL Developer which kind of includes a client, maybe?, thick driver, thin driver. There are so many approaches to do similar things. There's a steep learning curve to sort through all the different concepts and terminology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The client is JUST a client.

You'll want to download the Oracle Database installs. The easiest would be the XE (Express Edition) - it's free, and gets going on windows or linux pretty quick.

You'll then install the server software and THEN create a database. Then you can use your client to connect to said database. You can use your client now to connect to any Oracle database running on any server that you can see on your network.

There are more alternatives.

I talk about this in more detail [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/).

Comment: At first I thought Instant Client was a yet lite-er version of XE, and I was trying to find a way to use it as such. However, what you've described is what I've come to realize from reading about it, but I wasn't sure. I've used XE before, and I know what I'm doing with that, so I'll go that route. Thanks so much for clearing this up, it was really frustrating me trying to use this the wrong way.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but happy to hear you're on the right path. Let us know if you need anything else going forward.

Comment: I've made some description tweaks to the OTN Instant Client page and sent a note to the Oracle doc writer to improve the description in the manual.